# Javascript is not working on Pidora os(on Raspberry Pi device) browser

Tags: javascript, file, raspberry-pi

This is my javascript code

```
window.setInterval(backClick, 500);

function backClick(){
   alert("ok");
}
```

I want to call backClick function time to time.This code is working on my pc. But it is not working on rasberypi device.pls help me...

Answer (score 0):

try to leave a generic, unnamed (anonymous) function..

```
setInterval(function () { 
                     alert("ok");
                        }, 500);
```